# Why if I put resolve() into the callback function of fs, the promise doesn't return

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

(tips: I'm using a nodejs framework `eggjs` based on `koa`)

The code below can run successfully.But if I put `resolve()` into callback function of `fs.renameSync()`, the promise won't return any thing, and the request keeps **pending** status.

What causes this? Does this have to do with the order of execution?

```js
 async uploadAsset(assetName, file) {
    const { app } = this;
    const logger = this.logger;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      fs.renameSync(file.filepath, `${app.config.multipart.projectAssetLocalPath}${assetName}`, err => {
        if (err) {
          logger.warn(err);
          reject();
        }
      });
      resolve();
    });
  }
```

Comment: There's no reason I know of to wrap a synchronous `fs.renameSync()` in a promise.  It just makes it harder to use.

Comment: are you calling `.then()` on the other side?  like, `uploadAsset('name', file).then(function() {...});`?

Comment: And, there's no callback for `fs.renameSync()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renameSync` is a synchronous version of `rename`. It does not accept a callback as an argument; it only accepts an [oldpath and a newpath](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_renamesync_oldpath_newpath). If you pass a third argument, it will be ignored; the callback function you're passing is never called.

If you want this to be callback-based, use `fs.rename` instead, which *does* take a callback.

Your `resolve` is also *outside* the callback at the moment, when it should be inside:

```
async uploadAsset(assetName, file) {
  const { app } = this;
  const logger = this.logger;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.rename(file.filepath, `${app.config.multipart.projectAssetLocalPath}${assetName}`, err => {
      if (err) {
        logger.warn(err);
        reject();
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Or use `fs.promises` instead, to accomplish this without constructing the Promise yourself.

```
async uploadAsset(assetName, file) {
  const { app } = this;
  const logger = this.logger;
  return fs.promises.rename(file.filepath, `${app.config.multipart.projectAssetLocalPath}${assetName}`)
    .catch((err) => {
      logger.warn(err);
      throw new Error(err);
    });
}
```